# How can I show that the following number is not divisible by $p$ prime?

Tags: divisibility

Let $p$ be a prime number.
Let $k$ be some natural number and $r$ be some nonnegative integer.

Then, I want to show that for $1\leq i\leq p^k-1$,

\begin{equation*}
\frac{p^{k+r}m-i}{p^k-i}
\end{equation*}
is not divisible by $p$, where $m$ is not divisible by $p$.

Can you give me a hint??

Comment: I assume those $j$'s should be $i$'s?  Also, is $r$ an integer?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Yes $j'$s are $i's$, and $r$ is integer. Thank you. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the whole fraction to be divisible by $p$, assuming $i$ is an integer, the numerator must be divisible by $p$.  The numerator is only divisible by $p$ when $i$ is divisible by $p$.  This just leaves the case $i=ap^n,n<k$ to consider.